# How to delete an array element in javascript without using any of built-in Array methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write my own implementation of array element deletion method. 
Why? - Because I am interested to know the algorithm behind the array element deletion and would like to take a stab at that.

I tried delete operator but it just sets the element to undefined. I don't want to use any of the existing built-in methods of Arrays such as splice, shift, pop, etc.

Is it even possible to achieve this? I am not looking for whole script but an idea and a direction on how to proceed would help. May be suggest me the topics I could explore to get an answer.

Thanks.

P.S-1: I have seen other posts related to array element deletion but they all use splice, pop, shift methods.

P.S-2: If you are going to downvote this question atleast have some courtesy to explain why you are downvoting. Otherwise I could only assume your life is extremely miserable and you need to downvote random questions posted on this forum to cure your misery.

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? Split, pop, shift, .. works just fine? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Homework?

Comment: If you want to do this without any of those methods, presumably you are trying to learn. If that is the case, why are you asking for other people to give you the implementation?

Comment: "my own implementation of array element delete method": `Array.prototype` doesn't have a delete method. That method only applies to objects.

Comment: I wanted to learn the internals and was wondering if you anyone have tried this. I am not trying to re-invent the wheel. This is just curiosity on how deletion work internally. No, this is not a homework but more of curiosity. Those who down voted me - appreciate if you tell me why? This isn't a bad question and haven't violated any rules i suppose.

Comment: @Andy: I understand that Array doesn't have delete method. It's just a sentence to explain what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own deletion method:

```
Array.prototype.flush = function() {console.log(this.length = 0);}
```

Usage:

```
var test = [1, 2, 3];
alert(test);
test.flush();
alert(test);
```

**UPDATE 1**
Deletion method: if I understand correct: 
specify position, delete one element. If not better use is Array.prototype.splice(), anyhow, if you asked:

Code:

```
Array.prototype.delete = function(pos){ 
 if (pos < this.lenght) {
  this.splice(pos, 1);  
  return this
 } 
 throw "index " + pos + " outside of array length";
}
```

usage:

```
var test = [1, 2, 3];
    alert(test);
    test.delete (1);
    alert(test);
```

**UPDATE 2**
JavaScript Array delete without prototype methods usage:

```
Array.prototype.delete = function (pos) {
  if (!this.length) throw 'array is empty';
  if (pos < this.length) {
    for (var i = pos; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
      if (i < pos) continue;
      this[i] = this[i + 1];
    }
    this.length = this.length - 1;
    return this;
  }
  throw 'index ' + pos + ' outside of array length';
}
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
foo.delete(0);
alert(foo);
foo.delete(0);
alert(foo);
foo.delete(0);
alert(foo);
foo.delete(0);
alert(foo);
```

Comment: Your code empties the array. What I am looking is how to delete specific element in an array.

Comment: If this is not what you are looking for (check update), just play around with Array.prototype.splice()

Comment: if you read my posting again, you will see I have mentioned that I dont want to use any of the built-in functions such as splice.

Comment: I miss read your post, check last update, but this is very stupid.

Comment: Yeah something like that. I was trying the same logic earlier by shifting the elements. It works but if the array is really large it will result in lot of assignment operations. So I was wondering if there is a effective way. I was also googling to find the implementation details of splice(), slice(), etc of Array.prototype but still searching. Thanks for taking the time and effort to respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tab=[1,2,3,4,5]
    function new_splice(index,arr){
        for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
            if(i==index-1){
                for(j=i;j<arr.length-1;j++)
                    arr[j]=arr[j+1]
            }
            new_arr=[];
            for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
                new_arr[i]=arr[i]
        return new_arr;
    }
    document.write(new_splice(1,tab))
```